# Text not aligning in HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css, firebug

Here is my markup

```
     <div class="code php">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="line-numbers">1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15 </div>
        <code>
    <?php
        $people = array('henry', 'foo', array('jeff', 'bar'), 'tom', 'barry');

        foreach($people as $person) {

            if (is_array($person) {
                  foreach($person as $innerPerson) {
                      if ($innerPerson == 'bar') {
                          break 2;
                      }              
                   }
            }
        }
    ?>
        </code>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE**

Fixed formatting for above. Was important because it uses `white-space: pre` in the CSS.

And here is my CSS

```
.code {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0.3em;
    padding: 0.8em;

}

.code .container {
    background: #efe;
    white-space: pre;
    border-left: 3px solid #6d9743;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    padding: 0.8em;

}

.code .caption {
    display: block;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    color: #333;
}

code,
.code .line-numbers {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, Courier New, serif;
    border: 0px solid red;
}

.code .line-numbers {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0.8em;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

And here is what is happening!

[damn http://alexanderdickson.com/so.png](http://alexanderdickson.com/so.png)

Notice how the line numbers are not matching up? It used to work perfectly. I recently played around with it a lot, to allow myself to add a caption and I think I've buggered it. (I really do need to look into version control!)

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've tried line height, padding, etc and examined as best as I could with Firebug.

Thanks

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Real live example here: http://www.alexanderdickson.com/articles/php/exiting-a-loop-early/

Note: I have tried removing all the code formatting (all the `<spans>` etc) but there is still a problem!

**FIXED**

It is now working with this CSS

```
.code {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0.3em;
    padding: 0.8em;

}

.code .container {
    background: #efe;
    border-left: 3px solid #6d9743;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.8em;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, Courier New, serif;

}

.code .line-numbers {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    width: 2em;
}

.code .caption {
    display: block;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: if your sole aim is to display code, then why not use syntaxhighlighter. http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter
it is the most simple and efficient way to display code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the line-height to the .line-numbers

This works for me:

```
.code {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0.3em;
    padding: 0.8em;

}

.code .container {
    background: #efe;
    white-space: pre;
    border-left: 3px solid #6d9743;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.8em;

}

code {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.code .caption {
    display: block;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    color: #333;
}

code, .code .line-numbers {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, Courier New, serif;
    border: 0px solid red;
}

.code .line-numbers {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

I will try to post a screenshot.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>    
 <div class="code php">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="line-numbers">
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15 </div>
        <code>
    &lt;?php
        $people = array('henry', 'foo', array('jeff', 'bar'), 'tom', 'barry');

        foreach($people as $person) {

            if (is_array($person) {
                  foreach($person as $innerPerson) {
                      if ($innerPerson == 'bar') {
                          break 2;
                      }              
                   }
            }
        }
    ?&gt;
        </code>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: It should inherit it. When I view computed styles in Firebug too, they are the exact same (in `<code>` and `<div class="line-numbers">`)

Comment: I know it "should", but did you try it?

Comment: @Martin - No, I haven't tried it. Will test soon. If it works, I'll accept your answer. +1 for coming back and making an update :) Thank you

Comment: I placed your CSS in, and while *some* of them line up, they don't all do! Quite frustrating!

Comment: I agree with Martin, it's definitely a matter of line-height, but also different font-size can affect how everything lines-up. I'd do smt in the fashion of `div.container > div, div.container > code { line-height: 1.5em; font-size: 12px; }`

Answer (score 1):

your calling a class ".code" in your css, but code is a tag not a class, so it'd be just "code" in your css

Comment: I have both - the main div's class is code, and I have a code element nested within this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your class: "code php"

[edit: no coffee]

Remove complexity.  What is in your code class definition?  In your php class definition?  If php comes comes second and you're changing code, your changes won't show.  Side note: use something more descriptive than code, since code is an element name.  I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter, but it helps readability and prevents simple errors like the difference between code and .code not to mention #code.

Comment: That's valid. I have 2 classes.

Comment: That's just multiple class names: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class

Comment: So this answer sucks.  Sorry guys.